# Repetitive CURL commands via the terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, curl

I have a list of 3000 unique IDs.

I want to run multiple CURL commands, like so:

```
$ curl -i -u user:password -X DELETE https://mywebsite.com/rest/v2/page/[UniqueID]/
$ curl -i -u user:password -X DELETE https://mywebsite.com/rest/v2/page/[UniqueID]/
$ curl -i -u user:password -X DELETE https://mywebsite.com/rest/v2/page/[UniqueID]/
```

etc.

Is there a way to do this non-manually, so that I'm not copying/pasting in each unique ID and pressing return on my mac terminal 3000 times?

Comment: what kind of list are you talking about?

Comment: do you want to do that in sql?

Comment: This is what scripting has been invented for. It does not matter what kind of scripting language you use. Any one will do. Some shell, php, python, brainfuck, whatever. You implement a tiny script that opens the list, enters a loop and makes one single request per loop iteration using always the next ID from the open list.

Comment: @baao The unique IDs are a bunch of different hashes in a .txt file.

Comment: @arkascha I get how to loop, but to run it would I still have to copy it all into the terminal, or is there another way?

Comment: Usually a script is stored in a separate file. That way you only need one single command to start that script from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bash brace expansion
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace

For example id 1,2,3,4

```
curl -i -u user:password -X DELETE https://mywebsite.com/rest/v2/page/{1,2,3,4}/
```

or id 1 up to 100

```
curl -i -u user:password -X DELETE https://mywebsite.com/rest/v2/page/{1..100}/
```

Comment: I suppose out-of-ordered numbers is still ok, like curl -i -u user:password -X DELETE https://mywebsite.com/rest/v2/page/{234023, 1223, 234, 8742}/